# Why is PHP no longer parsing correctly in my .html pages?

Tags: php

My site is with HostGator shared hosting (yes, I know, that’s my first mistake).  I'm looking to redesign it, but before I do, I need to fix a PHP parsing problem.

All of the site's pages are HTML (.html).  However, I have always used PHP to insert dates, times, random text, etc.  Suddenly, PHP stopped parsing in all .html pages of the site, even though I did not touch my htaccess file.  Simple PHP code no longer works.  For example:

```
<?php print date('Y'); ?>
```

My default PHP is set to PHP 5.6.  HostGator claims that it's "outside the scope of [their] service" to help me figure out what happened (even though it's obvious that they changed/updated something on their end).

The following worked perfectly in .htaccess for years, but now it results in a "500 error":

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .html
```

I have also individually tried each one of the following in htaccess, to no avail:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php
AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm
AddHandler php5-script .php .html .htm
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html`
```

Some of those options result in a "500 error," while the others have no effect at all.

I'd greatly appreciate some help in resolving this problem.  (Changing the extension to ".php" is not an option.)  Thank you!

UPDATE:  There is no updating "log" or "error" file anywhere in my FTP interface.  Also, the only entries in Hostgator's "Last 300 Error Log messages" page in cPanel look like this:

```
[Thu Nov 08 03:32:04 2018] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] SoftException in Application.cpp:313: File "/home4/.../public_html/index.html" is writeable by group, referer: https://www.********.com/
```

Comment: when you get the error 500, what do the server error log tell you?

Comment: Does a simple new php script with the content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` work?

Comment: Have you added?:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .html

Comment: @Kaddath, all I'm seeing in the "Last 300 Error Log messages" are entries about how the page I loaded is "writeable by group."

Comment: @Progman, I made a new file ("phpinfo.php") with "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" inside of it.  The webpage results in a 500 error.

Comment: @DieterKräutl, "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .html" results in the 500 error, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have the `display_errors` directive set to on? And the error level set to `E_ALL`?

Comment: @Jason Please edit your question to include the complete error messages from your "Last 300 Error Log messages" thing and explain what this "Last 300 Error Log messages" thing is. Also copy the content of the actual error log file of the apache server to your question.

Comment: @emix, yes, I do have the display_errors directive set to on and the error level set to E_ALL in the php.ini file, but this is Hostgator, so who knows what the heck is going on . . . .

Comment: If your error is "page is writeable by group", did you try changing the file permissions to 644?

Comment: @KarstenKoop, you rule!  Hostgator apparently changed the permissions of all .html files from 644 to 664 without telling me!  That was the problem.  Thank you so much!  Do you want to post your solution as a separate answer so that I can choose it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

```
File "/home4/.../public_html/index.html" is writeable by group
```

suggests that the problem is the file permissions of your html files. So change them from 664 to 644 to make them not-group-writeable.

Comment: Changing permissions from 664 to 644 fixed the problems!  PHP once again parses in the .html files!  Thank you!